# Identifying user through access_token or id_token when calling backend API

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, auth0

What is the proper way to identify a user in an API call?

I'm using the [`Auth0` service](https://auth0.com/) to secure my API and manage user authentication/sign up process. I "think" I'm clear about two things:

1. `access_token` gives the client app proper access to my backend API. In other words, I need to send an `access_token` with my API call to my backend so that I can access my API end points.
2. The primary purpose of `id_token` is to provide the backend API information about the user e.g. id, name, email, etc.

Assuming I'm right about these two points, how do I let the backend API know who the user is? I don't think I can send both `access_token` and `id_token` in the same call. Am I then making two calls?

I can certainly include user information in my API call payload but would that not be a security concern? Potentially a malicious user could change the user info before the API call and present himself/herself as someone else.

I'm unclear about the way of letting the backend API know who the user is.

P.S. Here's more info in case it's needed:

- All user authentication, sign up and tokens are handled by the [`Auth0` service](https://auth0.com/).
- My backend API is created in `ASP.NET Core` and is configured to accept `Auth0`
  tokens. This is working fine i.e. I send the `access_token` I get from `Auth0` in my API calls and I'm able to access my end points.
- I'm now developing a mobile app in `ReactNative` which authenticates users through `Auth0` and calls my `ASP.NET Core` backend API for all the functionality it provides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Sam's concerns and my preference is to keep access tokens small and confidential - containing just a user id that the API can read.

For further info I use claims in the API using this pattern, which is also commonly used by API gateways - such as AWS:
https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/

If it helps here is a [.Net Core class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthorizer.cs) that implements it.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly then that you only receive user Id in the access token and you do a look up for the user in your own database, then cache the user data for subsequent API calls? If so, this seems like a nice and clean approach but definitely costly. In my case, I use Azure Redis for caching data and pulling cached user data from an Azure service is way costlier than getting it from a token. I also tried putting additional user data inside the access token but running into some issues with that with the Auth0 service. Just want to follow the standard approach.

Comment: You are right that there is a cost - but you only pay the cost when an access token is first received - once every 60 minutes per user. You may prefer other solutions that achieve your goals of course. Out of interest there is a single page app online sample of mine here that you can quickly run to get a feel for end user performance - when you click Expire Token then Refresh, the API does the lookup: https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looks like the way you describe is the recommended way. This section of documentation on `Auth0` pretty much confirms your approach is the right way: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/why-use-access-tokens-to-secure-apis#how-not-to-use-tokens Unfortunately, in my case the cache doesn't come cheap because my app is a cloud app that uses Azure so the cost is a bit higher than caching data in server memory. Nevertheless, security is paramount so I'll consider it "cost of doing business". Thanks again for your help.